# Get a result for each day, instead of total in date range, with Google Analytics API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When doing a Google Analytics API query:

```
res = service.data().ga().get(ids='ga:152373812', start_date='7daysAgo', end_date='today',
          metrics='ga:users', segment='gaid::7yMBa3f7RimTf2SFtRQaRh').execute()

pprint(res)
```

I get the **total sum** of users for this date range (7 days ago to today):

```
...
u'rows': [[u'100']]
...
```

**How to get the results for each day instead?** e.g. something like:

```
{'2018-07-06': 7,
 ...
 '2018-07-12': 17,
 '2018-07-13': 5}
```

---

Here is the full report:

```
{u'columnHeaders': [{u'columnType': u'METRIC',
                     u'dataType': u'INTEGER',
                     u'name': u'ga:users'}],
 u'containsSampledData': False,
 u'id': u'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:...&metrics=ga:users&segment=gaid::...&start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=today',
 u'itemsPerPage': 1000,
 u'kind': u'analytics#gaData',
 u'profileInfo': {u'accountId': u'...',
                  u'internalWebPropertyId': u'...',
                  u'profileId': u'...',
                  u'profileName': u'...',
                  u'tableId': u'ga:...',
                  u'webPropertyId': u'...'},
 u'query': {u'end-date': u'today',
            u'ids': u'ga:...',
            u'max-results': 1000,
            u'metrics': [u'ga:users'],
            u'segment': u'gaid::...',
            u'start-date': u'7daysAgo',
            u'start-index': 1},
 u'rows': [[u'100']],
 u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:...&metrics=ga:users&segment=gaid::...&start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=today',
 u'totalResults': 1,
 u'totalsForAllResults': {u'ga:users': u'100'}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add a [`ga:date`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_date) dimension:

```
res = service.data().ga().get(..., dimensions='ga:date').execute()
```

which finally gives:

```
...
u'rows': [[u'20180620', u'9'],
          [u'20180621', u'10'],
          ...
          [u'20180630', u'7']]
...
```

Comment: Since you answered your own question, can you help me with a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66056818/programmatically-parsing-google-analytics-what-pages-do-your-users-visit-day