# Programmatically parsing Google Analytics "What pages do your users visit?" day by day?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am not a Google Analytics power user, but something tells me that if I wanted to parse out the "What pages do your users visit?" box:

[image]

It should be a lot easier to do it by individual day than manually clicking through "Today", "Yesterday", then selecting individual calendar dates using "Custom".  Unfortunately, if I click on the "PAGES REPORT" option and select the date range I'd like to explore in full (e.g., previous year or more), I can't see on what days what page was visited because the results are all binned together per page visited per date range, with no indication of the specific individual days that it was visited:

[image]

Is there a programmatic way (e.g., using an API) to cleanly query and parse Google Analytics "What pages do your users visit?" results to obtain day-by-day info without needing to select today, yesterday, the day before, etc. manually by hand hundreds of times?

The only relevant post I could find on this was: [Get a result for each day, instead of total in date range, with Google Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332720/get-a-result-for-each-day-instead-of-total-in-date-range-with-google-analytics) (but it wasn't particularly helpful to me)

Answer (score 0):

You have to select a date range and select `Date` as secondary dimension, so you can see pages visited in each day without doing it one day at a time.